# How to solve $\vert x+1 \vert \geq 2x-4$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

When solving modular inequalities with absolute values in both sides, it is told that one should square both sides of the equation. By using the same strategy on such an example:

$$\vert x+1 \vert \geq 2x-4$$

the answer presented below, obtained using that method, is not incorrect:

$$\vert x+1 \vert \geq 2x-4$$

$$(x+1)^2 \geq (2x-4)^2$$

$$x^2 - 6x + 5 \leq 0$$

$$\therefore \{x \ | \ 1 \leq x \leq 5 \}$$

The correct answer should be $$\{x \ | \ x \leq 5 \}$$

How should one go about solving that? Is the only possible way representing it graphically?

(couldn't find problems like this in pre calculus books)

Comment: $a \ge b$ does not imply  $a^2 \ge b^2$.  For example, $1 \ge -2$, but $1^2 < (-2)^2$.

Comment: @L.F. I see, therefore you could not generalize it, as opposed to when you have $\vert x+1 \vert > \vert 2x-4 \vert$, when you can actually state that $(x+1)^2 > (2x-3)^2$? Also, can it be stated that $\vert x+1 \vert > k$ guarantees that $(x+1)^2 > k^2$

Comment: Find (by squaring, just as you did) the zeroes of the function $f(x)=2x-4-|x+1|$; you'll arrive in $x=5$.  As a continuous function $f$ may only change its sign at this zero.

Answer (score 3):

> When solving modular inequalities with absolute values **in both sides**, it is told that one should square both sides of the equation.

I added the emphasis above. The inequality you are solving does not have the property of having absolute values on both sides, so it shouldn't be surprising  that applying the rule leads to a false conclusion.

The easiest way of solving your problem (apart from the graphical representation) is to separate the problem into two cases, one where $x<-1$ and the other where $x\geq -1$.

Comment: of course, and that is the reason for my question. "How should one go about solving that?"

Comment: @bru1987 I added another sentence to the answer: separate the cases $x<-1$ and $x\geq -1$.

Answer (score 1):

The way you proceed is not correct because

$$|A|\ge B \iff A^2\ge B^2$$

is not true in general, notably when $B<0$ and $|B|>|A|$.

To follow your idea, we need to proceed as follows:

- for $2x-4 <0 \iff \color{blue}{x<2}$ the inequality is always true (since the LHS is non negative)
- for $2x-4 \ge 0 \iff x\ge 2$ we can square both sides, as you did, to obtain  $\color{blue}{2 \leq x \leq 5}$

therefore, putting things togheter, the full solution is:

$$x<2 \quad \lor  \quad 2\leq x \leq 5 \quad \iff\quad x\le 5$$

This way is an alternative to the standard method to separate the problem into two cases according to the sign of the expression under absolute value.

Comment: Yes, we need the same sign (in both sides)  for squaring. (If the sign is negative, then the inequality will reverse.)

Comment: Exactly. Morover for equations in this form when $B<0$ all solution obtained from this conditions are good, then we can square and obtain the other piece of solutions for the case $B\ge0$.

Comment: The method is useful for inequalities in the form $\sqrt A\ge B$.

Answer (score 0):

Obviously there exists an $s\in \mathbb{R}$ such that

$|x+1| = 2x-4-s^2$ so we have $(x+1)^2=(2x-4-s^2)^2$ and solving for $x$

$$
3x^2-(4s^2+18)x+8s^2+15 = 0
$$

we have

$$
x = \cases{1 + \frac{s^2}{3}\\  5+s^2}\Rightarrow \cases{x\le 1\\ x\le 5}\Rightarrow x\le 5
$$

Answer (score 0):

To solve

$$|x+1|\geq2x-4$$

must explicit the module:

$$\text{If}\quad x+1>0\rightarrow x>-1\rightarrow |x+1|=x+1 \space\text{and the eq. becomes}$$

$$x+1\geq2x-4\rightarrow x\leq5\rightarrow x\in(-1,5]$$

$$\text{if}\quad x+1<0\rightarrow x<-1\rightarrow |x+1|=-x-1 \space \text{and the eq. becomes}$$

$$-x-1\geq2x-4\rightarrow 3x\leq3\rightarrow x\leq1\rightarrow x\in(-\infty,-1)\cap(-\infty,1]\rightarrow x\in(-\infty,-1)$$

if $x+1=0\rightarrow x=-1$ is a solution because $0\geq-6$

Now, $x$ would belongs to the set:

$$x\in(-\infty,-1)\cup\{-1\}\cup(-1,5]=(-\infty,5]$$